Running into "INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST" While Converting Lead
I have a custom Apex page(VisualForce Page) on the Lead Conversion Button
Along with the controller and apex class for lead conversion
There is a picklist field [Picklist__c]on the lead which is a restricted field
when converting the lead it gives me the following error:
ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for restricted picklist field: : [Picklist__c]
I have checked the API name and active values of the picklist they all are correct.
Unfortunately, I can't share my code here.
Should I debug this field or anything else
Suggestions are welcomed!

You need to provide more detail.  Are you mapping that Lead picklist field to a field in the Contact or Opportunity?  Does the target field have the same values as the Lead picklist field?  Please [edit] your post to include these details.

You can go to Opportunity > RecordTypes and look for the  [Picklist__c] in the Opportunity RecordType that produced the error. There are 2 columns to select the allowed values for that particular  [Picklist__c] for that Opportunity RecordType

How do you know it is the Opportunity object?  Couldn't it be the account or contact?  What if there are no record types on the object?

Sorry @DavidCheng. You are right. However, for any objet the sequence to solve this error is the same. If there are not record types.
